# JBoss web application - passing the entitymanager as an argument doesn't work

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss

I developed a JBoss social networking web application using the TicketMonster tutorial and application structure; my design involves different types of account privileges, and many services require checking user account details for the logged in user, and other data they'd like to view/access.

ex. Moderators can view disabled accounts and comments, while members can't.

For the above example, I'm using a method that creates a query that retrieves the user using their username:

    `Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select u from User u where u.username in :userName", User.class);
    query.setParameter("userName", username);
    User user = (User) query.getSingleResult();
    return user;`

Since different services use that method, I thought it would be a good idea to have it in the ServicesUtility class which takes the EntityManager in its constructor, and performs the queries on it, and returns the value. The problem is the entity manager in the ServiceUtility class doesn't accept the passed entityManager and remains null. The same method works within the Services, which I'm fine with, and wouldn't mind adding it to the BaseEntityService parent class, but I'm just wondering why it doesn't work.

Update: Here's the code for my ServiceUtility class:

`

```
public class ServiceUtility {

// @Inject
EntityManager em;

public ServiceUtility(EntityManager entityManager){
    em = entityManager;
}

public User getUserFromUsername(String username){
    try{

        Query query = em.createQuery("select u from User u where u.username in :userName", User.class);
        query.setParameter("userName", username);
        User user = (User) query.getSingleResult();
        return user;
    } catch(Exception e) { //null, no results, constraints violation, exception (all types) - Note: must differentiate between types.
        return null;            
    }
}

public Thread getThreadFromTitle(String title){
    Query query = em.createQuery("select t from Thread t where t.title = :Title");
    query.setParameter("Title", title);
    return (Thread) query.getSingleResult();
}

public Thread getThreadFromId(Long id){
    Query query = em.createQuery("select t from Thread t where t.id = :Id");
    query.setParameter("Id", id);
    return (Thread) query.getSingleResult();
}

public Response badRequestResponse(String message){
    Map<String, Object> responseEntity = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    responseEntity.put("errors", Collections.singletonList(message));
    return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(responseEntity).build();
}
}
```

`

**UPDATE:**

Although I'm still very interested in the solution to this problem, I worked around this issue by eliminating the need for methods that needed the entitymanager in ServiceUtility with this change to getSingleInstance:

`

```
@GET
@Path("/{id:[0-9][0-9]*}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public T getSingleInstance(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
    return getSingleInstance(entityClass, id);
}

public <X> X getSingleInstance(Class<X> type, Long id){
    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<X> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(type);
    Root<X> root = criteriaQuery.from(type);
    Predicate condition = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), id);
    criteriaQuery.select(criteriaQuery.getSelection()).where(condition);
    return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use dependency injection - `@Inject` (preferred) or `@PersistenceContext`, to inject the EntityManager dependency into `ServicesUtility`. In Java EE, constructor injector is not preferred/unsupported over field injection, so it makes sense to use field injection.

As long as the lifecycle of the bean `ServicesUtility` is managed by the container (CDI container or otherwise), the `EntityManager` field in it would not be null during typical method invocation.

[There is a CDI producer method](https://github.com/jboss-developer/ticket-monster/blob/2.7.0.Final-with-tutorials/demo/src/main/java/org/jboss/examples/ticketmonster/util/Resources.java#L31) in TicketMonster, that demonstrates how to write a producer method to produce an `EntityManager`. The CDI container would use this producer to inject the `EntityManager` into any desired injection points declared by the developer (you); for instance, [this is how the `BaseEntityService` receives it's `EntityManager` reference](https://github.com/jboss-developer/ticket-monster/blob/2.7.0.Final-with-tutorials/demo/src/main/java/org/jboss/examples/ticketmonster/rest/BaseEntityService.java#L71-L72).

Comment: I'm using Resources.java already, and have used it for injecting the EntityManager in my BaseEntityService class; using @Inject did not work in ServiceUtility either, as you can see I've commented it out at the field declaration in the code above. It still gave a null value to my EntityManager, and threw a NullPointerException on it. Could there be another cause to this issue?

Comment: On a side note, I don't understand Resources.java